# Import Freeze Panes - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I m using the below code to insert Freeze Panes (working perfectly) but i m wondering if there is a way to import Freezing Panes using sheet `Name` or `Codename` avoiding `ActiveSheet`. Thanks in advance!

```
'Set freeze
With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 3
    .SplitRow = 1
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but to avoid the ActiveWindow firing on the wrong sheet, you could use a `.select` or to activate the correct sheet and range by name as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `FreezePanes` property is a property of the `Window` object, you cannot use it for a worksheet directly.

Instead you must use `.Activate` to activate the desired worksheet as described in the documentation of the [Window.FreezePanes property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.freezepanes).

> ```
> Workbooks("BOOK1.XLS").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
> ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
> ```